# Change the ngx-datatable-column name dynamically

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-material, ngx-datatable

I'm using a component `ngx-datatable` angular version 9. I'm trying change the props `name`dynamically using a *ngIf command.

**Problem:** I want to using a attribute the list to show the right name.

**Code:**

```
    <ngx-datatable-column *ngIf="id == 0 "
      [cellClass]="'alinha-centralizado-global'"
      [headerClass]="'alinha-centralizado-global'"
      name="{{ 'name1' | translate }}"
      prop="fullName"
      [flexGrow]="2"
    >
   <ngx-datatable-column *ngIf="id == 1 "
      [cellClass]="'alinha-centralizado-global'"
      [headerClass]="'alinha-centralizado-global'"
      name="{{ 'name2' | translate }}"
      prop="fullName"
      [flexGrow]="2"
    > 
      <ng-template let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        <span title="{{ value }}">
          {{ value | fullName }}
        </span>
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
```

The `name1` and `name2`are in the `pt.json`. And the `id`is the `[rows]="list"` attribute. Of course doesn't work. Does anyone have any idea how to change the `ngx-datatable-column` props `name` dynamically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a beginner question. The correct way to do show the props's `ngx-datatable-column` `name` is to with in the `.html` file write like this:

```
  <ngx-datatable-column 
      [cellClass]="'alinha-centralizado-global'"
      [headerClass]="'alinha-centralizado-global'"
      prop="fullName"
      [flexGrow]="2"
    >
      <ng-template ngx-datatable-header-template>
          <span>{{ getName() }}</span>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        <span title="{{ value }}">
          {{ value | fullName }}
        </span>
      </ng-templa`enter code here`te>
    </ngx-datatable-column>`enter code here`
```

And in the `.ts` file you create a method `getName()` with the condition to show `name` dinamicatilly.